# Visual Studio crashing when adding a controller

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently teaching an intermediate class on C# using MVC4 and EF (believe it is 5). It is installed on all the machines in the lab we use. Completely fresh install on the machines using Visual Studio 2010 (unfortunately this is a licensing requirement).

I have been using my computer fine for the last few weeks and then the other day when right clicking on controllers and clicking add controller my VS froze. As did about half the class' too. The other half were able to select scaffolding info and create the controllers and move on with their lives.

No error was given though and will only hang at that point. I run windows 8 but the lab computers (about 10 hung) are windows 7 machines.

Any suggestions or insight I just dont know about?

Comment: Do you have the latest service pack installed?

Comment: Perhaps there is a memory leak issue with Visual Studio causing the crash? Check that you have all of the latest updates and service packs installed.

Comment: What is the current correct service pack version?

Answer (score 1):

To find out if your problem is caused by a misbehaving add-in, run Visual Studio in safe mode from the command-line:

```
c:\> devenv /SafeMode
```

Then try to create a controller again.

If it works, disable any installed add-ins one by one to find out which one is causing the problem and update/remove it(or contact appropriate tech support).

If not, you are likely to deal with a corrupt installation in which case it's probably wise to reinstall Visual Studio.

Note: [Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691) is the latest service pack for VS 2010.